# Bug in the tag selection

Tags: bug, tags

The placeholder text is **masked from the right end** and the **bracket is missing** too:

[image]

**Zoomed in:**

[image]

Comment: Wow, I didn't found that

Comment: No problem, it wasn't tagged [tag:tags] and it took me a minute or two to find it as well. I just knew it was asked before :)